# Searching records from 2 tables with Local SQL gives double answers

Tags: sql, local, paradox

I have a problem which I try to solve with Local SQL, but I can't find any solution. Can anybody give me a hint?

I have 2 Paradox tables Art.DB and Bet.DB

`Art` has 4 columns:

```
Datum, Object, Nr, Summa

Datum        Object     Nr     Summa
------------------------------------
2023-01-01   Tools      100    5000
2023-01-01   Bags       100    1000
2023-02-01   Tyres      101    4000 
2023-03-01   Cart       102    5700
```

`Bet` has 3 columns:

```
Nr, Type, Summa   

Nr     Type    Summa
---------------------
100    Card    5000
100    Cash    1000 
101    Card    4000
102    Cash    5700
```

I want to summarize the sales receipts, which is Nr

The SQL I use is

```
SELECT
    a.Nr, SUM(Summa) AS Summa 
FROM
    Art AS a, Bet AS b 
WHERE
    a.Nr = b.Nr
GROUP BY
    a.nr 
ORDER BY
    Nr
```

My problem is that I get double Summa because 2 payments with different methods for Nr = 100

```
Nr    Summa
-----------
100   12000
101    4000
102    5700
```

I am expecting a sum of 6000 and not 12000 for Nr 100. I understand why I get this result, but how should I write the SQL statement to get the desired result?

Comment: GROUP BY in a subquery before joining.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which summa column to be taken from Art or Bet. Change the sum according to your needs

here is the code

```
-- Calculate sum for each unique 'Nr' by joining 'Art' and 'Bet' tables
SELECT
    a.Nr,
    COALESCE(SUM(b.Summa), 0) AS TotalSum
FROM
    -- Subquery retrieves distinct 'Nr' values from 'Art'
    (SELECT DISTINCT Nr FROM Art) AS a
LEFT JOIN
    Bet AS b ON a.Nr = b.Nr
GROUP BY
    a.Nr
ORDER BY
    a.Nr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tables as structured do not represent a coherent model. With no uniqueness constraint on `[Nr]` in either table, you cannot expect to execute a meaningful query.

For example, there is no way to tell whether (case 1) the `tools` were paid by `card` and the `bags` were paid by `cash`, or (case 2) the `tools` were paid by `cash` and the `bags` were paid by `card`. All four records are linked by the key value `Nr`.

Of course, a person could *guess* that the `tools` were paid by `card` and the `bags` were paid by `cash` by looking at the corresponding `[Summa]` values. But this will not always be possible because the values may not be different.

Besides, `[Summa]` is not part of the key of either table, and the BDE is not allowed to make guesses.

However, I am allowed to make guesses, so here is what I guess your table structure should be:

`Art` has 4 columns:

```
Datum, Object, Nr, Summa

    Datum        Object     Nr     Summa
    ------------------------------------
    2023-01-01   Tools      100    5000
    2023-01-01   Bags       101    1000
    2023-02-01   Tyres      100    4000 
    2023-03-01   Cart       101    5700
```

`Bet` has 2 columns:

```
Nr, Type   

Nr     Type
-----------
100    Card
101    Cash
```

Summa values must not appear in more than one table.

`Bet` is a *lookup* table that holds only the payment type definitions.

`[Nr]` in `Bet` is constrained to be unique.

`[Nr]` in `Art` defines the payment type for each record.

This data model is far from complete. In particular, `Bet` needs to have a unique primary key because otherwise duplicate records can appear.